# Mac Outlook 2011 with GMail IMAP: Folders (Gmail Labels) not updating

Tags: gmail, imap, microsoft-outlook-2011, gmail-imap

So I've been following [this](http://www.macstories.net/tutorials/how-to-wrangle-outlook-2011-to-work-with-gmail/) guide to getting GMail IMAP to play nice with Microsoft Outlook 2011, and I've successfully got the GMail Labels to show up nicely as folders, and all existing messages have been downloaded in Outlook.

However, there is one crucial shortcoming.

I have server-side filters (that is, GMail filters) that archive certain messages when received (remove from Inbox and apply Label). However, when I get such a new message, Outlook doesn't update the new message count on the folder or have the little "new message" notification **unless** I manually click "Send/Receive". Then it'll discover the new message that had been archived and labelled by GMail, and notify me.

Messages that aren't filtered by any GMail filter (that is, that remain in the inbox), show up immediately when they arrive, with no problem.

Anyone have any ideas for what causes this, or have any workarounds? Apple Mail seems to have no problem notifying me of new messages in the folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

Outlook Preferences -> Schedules -> Double click Send & Receive All -> Go to your account under "Action" -> Click here for account options -> Make sure the folders are selected for syncing.